# use of several \ref using hypcap and pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to use several `\ref` with `hypcap` and `pgfplots` but they don't seem to work together. If I get rid of the `hypcap` stuff, my `pgfplots` `\ref` works fine. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % accents 8 bits dans le fichier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % accents codés dans la fonte
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ec]{aeguill}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Set1}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\newcommand{\gray}[1]{ \textcolor{gray}{#1} }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\capstart
%<*mytag>
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
scale=2,
title={Amplitude de $x(t)$ \gray{(ou de la charge $q(t)$)} en fonction de la pulsation $\omega$},
xlabel={$\omega$}, ylabel={$X_m(\omega)$ \gray{(ou $q_m(\omega)$)}}, xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.1, ymin=0, ymax=12,
width=190pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
xtick={0,1,2},
xticklabels={0,$\omega_0$,$2\omega_0$},
ytick={2,4,6,8,10},
yticklabels={,,,,$\approx QX_0$},
legend style={at={(0.7,0.7)},anchor=west,cells={anchor=west}},
legend entries={$Q=10$,$Q=4$,$Q=2$,$Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,$Q=0.1$}
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{10,4,2,0.707,0.1} {                     % boucle de tracé
    \addplot+ [ no marks, thick, samples=1000, domain = 0 : 2] (\x,{ 1/sqrt( (1-\x^2)^2 + \x^2/(#1)^2 ) });
                \label{pgfplots:XmQ#1}
    } ;
%pointillés
\draw [very thin, dashed, index of colormap=0 of Set1] (1,0) -- (1,10) (0,10) -- (1,10);
\draw (0,9.3) node [color=gray, left] {(ou $QCE_0$)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
%</mytag>
\caption{Amplitude de l'élongation} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\textbf{Si la résonance est aiguë} (par exemple pour la courbe \ref{pgfplots:XmQ10}) blabla\\
On peut remarquer que plus $Q$ diminue, plus $\omega_r$ diminue (par exemple pour les courbes \ref{pgfplots:XmQ4} et \ref{pgfplots:XmQ2}) et qu'il n'y a plus de résonance pour 
$Q\leq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (par exemple pour les courbes \ref{pgfplots:XmQ0.707} et \ref{pgfplots:XmQ0.1}).\\
\\
\\
Comme on peut le voir sur la courbe \ref{fig:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry to see how my code uploaded again...

Comment: it seems like defining 2 types of \label in the figure environement is an issue...

Comment: Unrelated: remove the call to the obsolete package `aeguill`.

Comment: Unrelated: Remove environment `center` outside of `figure` and put `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: I get some "missing \endcsname inserted